# An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details godday windows hosting

Tags: error, installation, magento-2.1.7

I have uploaded **Magento 2.1.7** on **godaddy windows shared hosting**.

I uploaded all files and restore database from localhost but this error happened.

please help me.

Comment: What is the issue.Could you please  explain?

Answer (score 0):

To know more about the error, go to the **document root** of your project and then navigate to **/var/log/exception.log**.

You will find the error details there.

If, from next time you want to see the error details on the page, then you need to go to **/pub/errors/** folder and rename **local.xml.sample** to **local.xml**. Also check **`<action>..</action>`** section should have **print** in it.